# About the speed in "for"

Tags: c#-4.0, .net-4.0

There was a task to know which code is faster and why:

```
//A
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        Int32[] a = new Int32[10000000];
        int len = a.Length;
        sw.Start();
        //for (Int32 index = 0; index < len; index++)
        //{

        //    a[index] = 6;
        //}
        //sw.Stop();


//B
        for (Int32 index = 0; index < a.Length; index++)
        {

            a[index] = 6;
        }
        sw.Stop();

        var time = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

The avarage time of approach B is  little **more** than A. Does anybody explain why?

Comment: Besides being a *flawed micro benchmark*, I suspect `a.Length` may take "a little more time" than `len`. (The compiler and JIT'er can be much more aggressive about *caching* the *local variable* `len`, in both MSIL and the generated JIT code, for instance. What if `a.Length` had a *side-effect* or if the backing property value changed? Clearly that can't be *not* accounted for!) However, in the end: It Just Doesn't Matter.

Comment: Although, I guess a "better" question might be: "Why doesn't the JIT optimize array.Length as well as it optimizes a local variable copy of array.Length?" *That* more focused query may actually lead somewhere (e.g. since it can be assumed that the length of an array is fixed and I *think* that access to `a` can be optimized here)... and would require *looking at the precise JIT'ed instructions*. In the end though, not something I find particularly interesting :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be because you are polling the length of the array each time you loop, whereas the A approach only has to check a cached value of the length. So, ultimately, this comes down to the idea of [caching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_%28computing%29)

Answer (score 0):

In case B, each time through the loop, runtime is calling code to get the length of the array.

In A, this is done once and the result saved.

I've always thought that the runtime would optimize that loop and they would be the same. Are your results significantly different? Have you run the test a few time to see that it is consistently different?